# Removing the Ubuntu bootloader from Ubuntu/Windows 10 Dual Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, grub, bootloader

I am removing Ubuntu (from the Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual-boot) because something happened to it and it just "broke". I could not reinstall since it did not give me the options to do so when I followed the steps showed online (assuming because it has indeed been broken). So I am just going to remove it entirely and either install it again or install Linux Mint.

I have removed the partition through Windows and I have restored the size of my drives. Now all that is left is the step that removes the Linux bootloader and replaces it with the Windows 10 bootloader. I have no Windows 10 disk and when I try to make a USB version of it, I do not have the required size since selecting the *Back up system files to the recovery drive* takes 16 GB and I only have 8 GB.

***Side Question*: To those who are experts in Linux and Windows, can I untick the box that backs up the system files so that the size becomes 512 MB instead of 16 GB on my USB or are those system files necessary in order to fix the bootloader?**

I cannot afford to buy a 16 GB USB drive at the moment being a seriously broke college student with a lot of bills. Is there a way to remove the Ubuntu bootloader without using a disk or USB drive? I have found some stuff on running

> bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr

though the command prompt as ADMIN.
I honestly do not know what that command even means.
I actually installed the Ubuntu partition on the D drive.
I ran that command and also the command replacing 'c' with 'd' and I got
[image]

Will this suffice? 
If I were to leave the Ubuntu bootloader alone and just learn to live with it and install Mint or another Ubuntu, what can happen?

Edit: Windows did the whole update thing so the computer rebooted and it threw me to a page with grub and errors.